# Can a non-trunking SVI interface be assigned to two VLANs?

Tags: vlan

As per our network monitoring device, One of the  Catalyst 6807 in the network  have 2 vlans assigned to SVI interface . I am not sure if this is misconfiguration . I wanted to know if this is possible to assign multiple vlans to an SVI .

Comment: Hello and welcome to Network Engineering. Please post the configuration you are referring to.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so you should accept it, so that the question doesn't keep popping up.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: cant find the option to set the question as answered

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't make sense. An SVI is the virtual interface entity in a VLAN. If you want interfaces in two different VLANs you need to create two SVIs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've confused VRFs and SVIs.
VRFs can handle the routing for multiple SVIs, segregating the traffic from some VLANs from others.

--

Every SVI is just an IP address in a Layer 3 VLAN, so, you can have more than one IP on an SVI, but each SVI is in its own VLAN.

--

Think of it like this: each VLAN can get a virtual interface it is applied to, which can be assigned IP address(es) and Net Mask(s).

It would be like assigning an IP address to a given physical port, but instead it's to a virtual port, you can't put that port into two VLANs without it being a trunk, and a trunk port can't have an IP address assigned to it.

So each Layer 3 VLAN is basically a virtual Access-port assigned to the given access VLAN, assigned a given IP address.

The syntax even lends itself to this interpretation:

```
int vlan 300
 description SVI_VAN_300
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip address 10.10.10.254 255.255.255.0 secondary
```

Very similar to the traditional port:

```
int e1/48/2
  description routed port on vlan 300
  switchport mode access
  switchport access vlan 300
  ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
  ip address 10.10.10.254 255.255.255.0 secondary
```

You can't set a VLAN interface into access mode or assign it to a VLAN because that's inherent.